# Increase the size of byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, byte

I having a spring multipart controller, I am trying to upload files of 2GB - 5GB. Spring multipart resolves get the whole file in memory when i try to do file.getBytes() I get an error Required array length 2147483639 + 9 is too large.

It works well with file size of 2,147,483,647 bytes which is the max size of integer.

Any way to increase the capacity of byte array or any other way to handle large file using spring boot.

Using Java 17 and Spring boot 3 so Commons fileupload is not supported as its using javax

Comment: Is there a need to load 5GB file into memory ? Save it, load as InputStream (or don't save and take inputstream from request) and read with buffer, or if it's character file, use java's built-in FileReader (or find inputstream parser for your use-case)

Comment: Only issue with streaming is it will hold on to the instance and might not work in concurrent request or microservice architecture

Comment: What concurrent request do you mean ? when it comes to uploading file ? or microservice ? don't know how that is related. I think biggest issue here is that you want to hold 5 GB of data in memory. If your problem is architecture here, you might have done some bad decisions. Describing your exact use-case might be more explanatory

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not really a problem in Spring or in the ByteArray itself but it is a limitation of the java language itself. Historically the size of an array is tracked by an int value which is 32 bit so the maximum theoretical elements in an array could be 2^32 -1 ~= 2B elements. So, unfortunately, large files cannot be easily kept in memory to access them as a array of bytes. One solution could be to save them as a file on disk once they are uploaded and access their content via a Scanner or the NIO APIs (or with an external library such as Apache Commons I/O)

Comment: You explained it well the line Java limitation is hardly mentioned anywhere when I was searching for the issue

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna look at this article: Spring and Apache FileUpload

[Spring and Apache FileUpload](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-apache-file-upload)

Comment: Issue with this is commons file upload still uses javax pacakage but since servlet 3 and in spring boot 3 we cant use javax we have to use jakarta

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @CoderAkki. BTW I'm new to stack overflow, this is my second answer. I will soon adapt

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with large file uploads in Spring Boot, relying solely on in-memory storage may not be the most efficient approach. Uploading files of 2GB to 5GB can quickly exhaust the available memory and cause issues like the one you encountered.

To handle large file uploads in Spring Boot, it's recommended to use streaming techniques instead of storing the entire file in memory. One way to achieve this is by utilizing Spring's MultipartFile API combined with streaming libraries like Apache Commons IO or Java NIO.

Here's an example of how you can handle large file uploads using streaming with Spring Boot:

Add the necessary dependencies to your project. For Apache Commons IO, you can include the following dependency in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Modify your Spring controller to handle the file upload using streaming techniques. Instead of using file.getBytes(), you can process the file in chunks using a BufferedInputStream and write it to a temporary file or directly to a desired location.

   import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
   import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
   import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;

   @RestController
   public class FileUploadController {

   ```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try (BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream())) {
            // Specify the desired location or create a temporary file
            File outputFile = new File("/path/to/save/file.ext");

            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
                // Buffer size for reading from input stream
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error uploading file.");
        }
    }
   ```

   }

By using streaming techniques, you can avoid loading the entire file into memory and process it in smaller chunks, making it feasible to handle large file uploads in Spring Boot.

Comment: But if this over multiple instances over server wont it be a sticky session and the instance will be busy till the file is completly streamed and if any netwrok issue occurs client has to retrigger it

Comment: He wants to upload more than 2GB. It is netural that server can deal it with less efficient. But there are some advanced ways with wotking with files. Best one (I know) is S3 bucket. Backend do not operate anything with files. All things are dealt on front side